# Polynomial defined by the points it passes through

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

Supposing I have a number of points $(x_i, y_i)$ where the $x_i$:s are all different, how would I go about creating a polynomial that passes through those points? Of course, if the $y_i$:s are all 0, I can just use the factor theorem, but I cannot seem to find an easy way for non-zero values of $y$.

Comment: See [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: What you're looking for is called an [interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be solving a linear system of exation. In fact, if you have $k$ different points $(x_i,y_i)$, with $x_i$ different each other, you can costruct a polynomial: $$P(x)=a_{k-1}x^{k-1}+a_{k-2}x^{k-2}+a_1x+a_0$$
In particular, you have to solve for $(a_{k-1},a_{k-2},\cdots,a_1,a_0)$ in the following system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_{k-1}x_1^{k-1}+a_{k-2}x_1^{k-2}+\cdots+a_1x_{1}+a_0=y_1
\\ \vdots
\\a_{k-1}x_k^{k-1}+a_{k-2}x_k^{k-2}+\cdots+a_1x_{k}+a_0=y_k
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Just for completeness (and because @Peatherfed might not have seen these ideas before), I'm going to mention that the way you go from the points $(x_i,y_i)$ to the linear system is by plugging in the points to $P(x)$. Then $P(x_i) = y_i$ becomes the $i^{\text{th}}$ equation in the system, and you solve for the coefficients in P(x).

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can set up a linear system of equations for the coefficients. If there are $n$ different points, they define a polynomial of degree $n -1$. You end up tangled with [Vandermonde's determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), loads of fun that way.

In practice, you use the [Lagrange form of the interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), or it's [baricenyric form](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/barycentric.pdf). Packages like e.g. SciPy, NumPy (Python) or libraries for numerical computation have this built-in.